# Table coloring on selecting checkbox using AJAX,JS,JSP

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

Can somebody tell me how to color the whole table(every row of the table) , as of now i am able to color only first row of my table

My color function in jsp:-

```
function changeColor(rowID){
        var row = document.getElementById(rowID);

        var alternateRow = document.getElementById(rowID +'_alt');  
    if(row!=null){
        if(row.style.backgroundColor == '' || row.style.backgroundColor == '#ffffff'){
            row.style.backgroundColor = "#009966";
            return;
        }
        if(row.style.backgroundColor == '#009966'){
            row.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
            return;
        }    
    }
    if(alternateRow!=null){     
        if(alternateRow.style.backgroundColor == '' || alternateRow.style.backgroundColor == '#ffffff'){
            alternateRow.style.backgroundColor = "#009966";
            return;
        }
        if(alternateRow.style.backgroundColor == '#009966'){
            alternateRow.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your HTML is follows:-

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" name="testing" />Hello World
```

Use JQuery:

```
$("#test").click(function() {     
   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('tr').css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

Comment: @rcky: Have you tried your code with one or two lines with append? If not, try to run that.

Comment: @SivaCharan...........my code is working fine........the only problem with it is that it is coloring only  first row of the table on selecting checkbox whereas i want to color all the three rows in the table.......which i am not able to do.....i have not pasted jsp file here